# Turning the TV-B-Gone into a universal remote

Tags: microcontroller

Ok, so I don't really want to turn the TV-B-Gone into a universal remote, *specifically*, but I would like to know/learn how I could go about creating a universal remote (I merely thought that working off of the TV-B-Gone would be a good point to start).

So yeah, anyone have any ideas as to how to go about making a universal remote? (ie: Can change channels, volume, on/off, maybe even the tv source...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about the TV-B-Gone, but really you're looking to build an modulated infrared emitter. Infrared LEDs are pretty inexpensive, and I imagine they could be directly driven by the PWM available on the Arduino. Range may be an issue, and I don't have the time to do the math right now, but you may end up building a driver circuit where the PWM will drive an amplifier to power several IR LEDs as the per-pin limit is 40 mA (iirc). You may be able to drive the TV-B-Gone this way, but you may very well find it satisfying to build the IR emitter by yourself, and it shouldn't be too hard.

As far as the remote itself goes, my understanding is that the vast majority of consumer electronics all work on a 38 kHz modulation. The protocol used to convey data may vary, but once you get your PWM set to send the data at the right rate that's just an issue of how you turn the LED on an off, which is just a series of pulses that need to be in memory.  One way of capturing this data is, using a working remote control, build an IR receiver circuit (or attach an oscilloscope) to read the signals it sends. This is tedious, but definitely something you can do on your work bench if you try. Another method would be to try and find the breakdown of remote protocols on the Internet. The Linux IR group might be able to help with that, at http://www.lirc.org/. It will require tearing through some source code, and may not give you all the answers you want, but will avoid the tedious nature of brute-forcing the protocols out of existing remotes.

A quick Google query turned up [this article](http://www.designnews.com/article/327993-Gadget_Freak_Case_147_The_Ultimate_Universal_Remote_Control.php?nid=2337&rid=2897067) on a home-built IR remote control. The article and build itself may not be useful, since it goes a different hardware route, but the PDF attached on the build theory is sound and probably something worth reading (follow the link "build instructions").

Also, the same Google search turned up this Arduino "Universal Remote". A quick perusal only showed it controlling a ceiling fan, but there's lots of good information in [this article](http://zovirl.com/2008/11/12/building-a-universal-remote-with-an-arduino/).

Good luck, and keep us posted on how the build goes! By the time the project is done, perhaps all the information necessary will be in this thread, including a link to common codes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pointer to an [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/) on how to create an [Apple IR Remote](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Apple-Remote-Shield-for-the-Arduino/) from an Arduino -- a similar problem, with a step-by-step solution.

Answer (score 1):

Lou already gave an excellent explanation of how the IR module work, but I wanted to elaborate on a few of the approaches that can be taken.

A programmable, universal remote is like [this one](http://www.arcfn.com/2009/09/arduino-universal-remote-record-and.html) here. I consider this the old school universal remote. You point a plain remote you already have at the universal remote, you press a button (like Power) on the plain remote, then the universal remote records the IR signal, which it can then replay.

The Apple IR Remote W. Craig Trader mentioned already has the IR instructions programmed for Play, Pause, etc. for the Apple device.

The programmable, universal remote and the Apple IR remote both tend to be only compatible with the specific manufacturer's hardware they were programmed for. This is because each manufacturer has their unique IR signal codes. The TV-B-Gone's approach is store the Power Off code for hundreds of manufacturers around the world and literally iterate through each code, sending out the IR signal. This is why TV-B-Gone's site says "It may take up to 69 seconds for the television to turn off, but most TVs will turn off within the first few seconds."

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on an open source project that is essentially a network enabled universal remote.  The idea is, if you keep all your A/V equipment in a closet somewhere (with an Ethernet line into the closet) you can connect this device, and control your TV, cable, dvd player, etc. with any networked device.  Assuming you have wifi, for example, this means you can use your iPhone, laptop, or whatever, as a remote.

The basic pain is setup.  I don't know of any open source IR libraries so you will literally have to "teach" the device every code for every remote by pointing the remote at the device, telling it which button/device you are about to program through the web page interface, and pressing the button.  The codes will all be stored in EEPROM.  I haven't set up a site yet but I can probably give you schematic / pcb files if you're interested.  I'm just getting started on software.

Comment: Well, this could be interesting - now I want to "network" this thing so I can access it from work to operate stuff, turn my stuff on/off when I am not home to make thieves think I am home.

Comment: You could reverse-engineer the Logitech Harmony product range, that does literally what you're trying to do (with RF link and device IR profiles downloaded from web) :-) ...and BTW... with no feedback from devices, keeping device state synchronized to the remote is an impossible task. Already tried...